# make list with exact matches from another list python

Tags: python, list

I am making a list of elements which exist in another list. There are two conditions:

condition 1. Need exact matches, therefore I don't not use "if y in x".

condition 2. The order of the original list needs to be retained.

```
rhg_brands = ['Radisson Collection', 'Radisson Blu', 
                'Park Plaza', 'Radisson Red', 'Radisson']

brands_in_df = ['Radisson Collection', 
                'Park Plaza', 'Radisson Red', 'Radisson']

#remove brands from rhg_brands if they're not in the brands_in_df 
rhg_brands = set(rhg_brands).intersection(set(brands_in_df))  

#output:
{'Park Plaza', 'Radisson', 'Radisson Collection', 'Radisson Red'}
```

I would like the output to retain the order of the original list somehow.

Below is the example of the desired output:

```
{'Radisson Collection', 'Park Plaza', 'Radisson Red', 'Radisson', }
```

Comment: if it's a dictionary it will not have the same order, it will be sorted by the key values even because you will access the element by key and not more by index

Comment: `[x for x in brands_in_df if x in  rhg_brands]` why not?

Comment: @Carlo1585 it is set

Comment: Oh sorry, I just saw the result with {} and I miss understood sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "Desired output" is a set (curly braces), but you say you want a list. So, use a list comprehension as follows.

```
result = [x for x in rhg_brands if x in brands_in_df]

assert result==['Radisson Collection', 'Park Plaza', 'Radisson Red', 'Radisson' ]
```

Comment: if 'Radisson' in 'Radisson Collection' would return true for this no? I need exact matches

Comment: @Boosted_d16 i think no. and you can simple try it

Comment: It returns True. I used this and had to settle for sets to get exact matches.

Comment: @Boosted_d16 i tried the solution and all works fine, because in the solution the test is `Radisson` in the list `brands_in_df` and it is not the same the `'Radisson' in 'Radisson Collection'`

Comment: I'll give it a go

Comment: @Boosted_d16 Just try this code. The `assert` gives confirmation of the result.